# DOM order not respecting facet order in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Lightning Component that allows additional rows to be added in between existing rows. The rows are represented by a [facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_facets.htm):

```
<aura:attribute name="payments" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
```

and the helper code that adds a row is:

```
var index = ...;
$A.createComponent("c:payment", {...}, function(newComponent, status, error) {
    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
        var rows = component.get("v.payments");
        rows.splice(index, 0, newComponent);
        component.set("v.payments", rows);
    } else {
         ...
    }
}
```

I've added JavaScript debugging output to confirm that the `rows` array is being modified as I expect and debug markup to confirm the DOM order which is **not** consistent. The inconsistency is repeatable with the new rows appearing at about half as many rows down as I would expect from the index; I wonder if the logic that finds the DOM insertion point for the new DOM elements is getting it wrong.

What's causing this behavior? How can I fix it?

**PS**

In this failing case `c:payment` creates a `<tr>` inside a `<tbody>`. I have similar code creating a `<div>` inside a `<div class="slds-grid">` that doesn't have this problem.

**PPS**

Changed to using `<div>` and that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem.

The `c:payment` component had this markup:

```
<aura:component>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <c:service aura:id="service"/>
</aura:component>
```

and changing to this markup fixed the problem:

```
<aura:component>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <c:service aura:id="service"/>
    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

The `c:service` component follows the "Creating Data Services" pattern described in [Modularizing Code in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/12/lightning-components-code-sharing.html) so nominally does not contribute to the DOM as it only contains `aura:method` declarations. But its location is significant in this case.

Having wasted a lot of hours on this, a rule I will follow in future is to make sure all components have a single element at their root that contains all the HTML and all other referenced components.